# cant see my footer with ListActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, footer

I am trying to do footer to my custom list but still cant work it out.
My aim is just to add some button to end of the list.
I tried this:

```
adapter = new GeneralRssAdapter(this,R.layout.titlesrss, data);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    lv.addFooterView( inflater.inflate( R.layout.footer_layout, null ), null, false);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but still cant see any footer.
Heres my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconremove"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/delete"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconfav"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/rss" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

    </LinearLayout>
  <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

and the footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:src="@drawable/tutorialrss"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

hope you can HELP me:)

Comment: Menchikovasky have you tried to use the inflate method that takes another parameter which is boolean and set it to false like this : inflater.inflate( R.layout.footer_layout, null,false ) ?

Comment: but  I used it on my main post  lv.addFooterView( inflater.inflate( R.la.....

Comment: you are using the inflate method that takes only 2 parameters, try adding the boolean parameter and see if it will work

Comment: @Saksak the inflation is good. Menchikovasky Can you see the Listview's content?

Comment: I didn't understated what do you mean by that, this method can take 3 params..... please  give me an example how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 adapter = new GeneralRssAdapter(this,R.layout.titlesrss, data);
         LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View footer = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null);
choicelist.addFooterView(footer);
    choicelist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i have edited this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tutorialrss"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

for me its working plz check once.

[image]

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(this, data);
        ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View footer = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
        lvMain.addFooterView(footer);
        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: maybe some one just can tell me how to add a button to the end of my list? because when I tring to add button I see it on every item on my list

Comment: @Vitaly i edited the footer layout. See my edited answer. Try again

Comment: @VitalyMenchikovsky i attached a screenshots. For its working.. Check once

Answer (score 0):

What I do is set my footer/header in `setContentView()` then use`list` xml in adapter. I don't normally like one line answers but that's all I do